# Sass project structure

Tags: css, sass, structure, project, stylesheet

I'm building a project and I'm using SASS. The structure I'm using is something like this:

- sass/

  - base/

    - *_reset.scss*
    - *_typography.scss*
    - *...*
  - components/

    - *_buttons.scss*
    - *_calendar.scss*
    - *...*
  - helpers/

    - *_variables.scss*
    - *_mixins.scss*
    - *...*
  - layout/

    - *_header.scss*
    - *...*
  - pages/

    - *home.scss*
    - *contact.scss*
    - *...*
  - vendors/
  - vendors-extensions/
  - **main.scss**

Right now I import all partial files in `main.scss` - that creates my `common.css` file.

I wonder if I can create `common.css` without including `pages/` folder and create css file for each page such as `home.css`, `contact.css`. 
I don't know how to do it so I can use helpers, mixins, functions, variables in my pages' `.scss` and not include them many times.

Can you help me? :)

Comment: Read some inspiring articles like: http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project  , take a look at "one step futher" section of this article. There they split dirs into modules, and every dir has all.scss which you include in your main scss. you could go this way, if you have a large project,or like to organize things.

Comment: Thank you, but I'd rather go with that structure I've posted. :)
Maybe I could create something like "shared.scss" and then import there only variables, mixins and functions and then import it on every page scss. What do you think about it?

Comment: Of course you can. But compiling css for every page seprate is something like repeating ;)

Comment: But importing only mixins, variables, functions (not css features) doesn't repeat the code I believe.

Comment: What are you using to compile the scss? `home.scss` and `contact.scss` should generate corresponding CSS files because they're not partials i.e. no leading underscore in the file name